# How to run AutoScalling more then one time?

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling

I tried to create new node in k8s with the process of autoscalar

It is working well if I have 1 node and then it create new node

```
pod triggered scale-up: [{shoot--system-z1 1->2 (max: 20)}]
```

when I tried to do it in the second time when I have 2 nodes and it try to create the 3 node then I got an error

```
pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added)
```

This is the logs of the autosclar

```
{"log":"Pod xxxx can't be scheduled on shoot-system-z1, predicate checking error: node(s) didn't match node selector; predicateName=NodeAffinity; reasons: node(s) didn't match node
 selector; debugInfo=","pid":"1","severity":"I","source":"scale_up.go:288"}
```

Could you please advise me what do In need to check ?

Comment: What are you doing to trigger the cluster autoscaler?  The "it wouldn't fit" message means, if you have a pod that requests 16 GB of RAM, it will never be schedulable anywhere no matter how many nodes you allocate if the nodes only have 8 GB of RAM each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like in that final Pod you are trying to deploy is a [NodeAffinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity) rule that does not match any of your nodes and would also **not match if the autoscaler would add an additional node**. You might want to remove that rule.